# Parse Json Object into an two dimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, jscript

I want to parse a JSON Object into an two dimensional array. But my code don't work.
Here my example:

```
{
"test":[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Robert",
    "last_name": "Schwartz",
    "email": "rob23@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Lucy",
    "last_name": "Ballmer",
    "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Anna",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
  }
]
};
var as = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(as)
```

I thought an normalized array I can parse with the parse function. But it don't work.

The result array should be like that:

```
[[1,"Robert","Schwartz","rob23@gmail.com"],[2,"Lucy","Ballmer","lucyb56@gmail.com"],[3,"Anna","Smith", "annasmith23@gmail.com"]]
```

Thank you for all solutions.

Comment: `test` is not JSON. It's a JavaScript object. You can't parse a JavaScript object. JSON is a string format. You can only parse strings.

Comment: Sorry now I see it and correct it. Now it should be an JSON object. Right? Do you have an idea to parse it?

Comment: Okay, but can you show me how it look like for example with the test object?

Comment: What do you mean with JSON object? JSON is a text format. It's a string.

Comment: From an api I become the input ``` [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Robert",
    "last_name": "Schwartz",
    "email": "rob23@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Lucy",
    "last_name": "Ballmer",
    "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Anna",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
  }
] ``` and I will foramt it to an array.

Comment: The snippet in your comment is an array of objects. No JSON. If this is a string it's JSON but not a JSON array or JSON object. A JSON object is an instance of class `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

## Array of Object Values

Run the array through with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and have each object within the array be converted into an array of values with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). BTW parsing the array of objects is unnecessary, it's already formatted as an array of plain JavaScript objects correctly.

### `.map()` and `Object.values()` Methods

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first": "Robert",
    "last": "Schwartz",
    "email": "rob23@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first": "Lucy",
    "last": "Ballmer",
    "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Anna",
    "last": "Smith",
    "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
  }
];

const objToArrVal = arrOfObj => {
  return arrOfObj.map(obj => Object.values(obj));
}

console.log(objToArrVal(data));
```

An alternative way to the same result that may be JScript compatible is to:

1. Run the first object in the array of objects (ex. `arrayOfObjects[0]`) in a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to get an array of object keys (ex. `keyArray = ['id', 'first', 'last', 'email']`) -- (we are assuming that all objects have the same set of keys).
2. Once the array of keys has been made, we run each object of the `arrayOfObjects` in a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
3. On each iteration of the `for` loop we run the object in another `for` loop that will extract each of the object's values (`arrayOfObject[outerLoopCount][keyArray[innerLoopCount]]`) into a sub-array.
4. Once inner and outer loops have completed extracting the object's values into a sub-array (ex. `valueArray`) it is added to the final array of arrays (ex. `resultArray`).

### `for` Loop and `for...in` Loop

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "first": "Robert",
    "last": "Schwartz",
    "email": "rob23@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first": "Lucy",
    "last": "Ballmer",
    "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Anna",
    "last": "Smith",
    "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
  }
];

function forLoopAO(arrOfObj) {
  var keyArr = [];
  var result = [];

  for (var key in arrOfObj[0]) {
    keyArr.push(key);
  }

  for (var o = 0; o < arrOfObj.length; o++) {
    var obj = arrOfObj[o];
    var valArr = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < keyArr.length; k++) {
      valArr.push(obj[keyArr[k]]);
    }
    result.push(valArr);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(forLoopAO(data));
```

Comment: I correct it to an JSON object. Do you have an idea?

Comment: From what did you get that garbage? It looks like it's been nested arbitrarily in brackets just for kicks.

Comment: First of all it's just JSON, not JSON object. A JSON is a string that represents a data structure that when parsed could be a JavaScript Array or Object. So in order to avoid further confusion, wrap it in quotes.

Comment: you'r code is want I want , but JScript don't accept any map function or arrow functions.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the javascript tag?

Comment: @Rob98 See second demo of my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this, it will map over tests and return the array contain the values of each object :

```
const twoDimArr= test.map(obj => Object.values(obj))
```

Comment: Both the answers which are already posted mention this.

Comment: Do you have an idea with an normal loop because JScript don't accept arrow functions.

Comment: you can change it a normal function like so test.map( function(obj) {Object.values(obj)} )

Comment: but using map function is the same problem. I now that map functions arrow functions and the Object.values function don't work. I need a loop to an specific element.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for loop` should do it

```
let results = [];
for (let i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
   results.push(Object.values(test[i]));
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you don't have access to the `Object.values` function you can use another loop to iterate over the object keys and use them to access it's properties

```
let results = [];
for (let i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    for (let key in test[i]) {
        results.push(test[i][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I has is that the Object.values function don't work on JScript. Do you have an idea to solve the problem?

Comment: @Rob98, I've expanded my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse a JavaScript object. JSON is a text format. You can only parse text. The array is in the property `text` in your object. You can access it with either `.test` or `['test']`. Then you have to convert each object to an array of values. The simplest way to achieve this is with `map` and `Object.values`.

```js
const test = {
"test":[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Robert",
    "last_name": "Schwartz",
    "email": "rob23@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Lucy",
    "last_name": "Ballmer",
    "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Anna",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
  }
]
};
const as = test.test.map(el => Object.values(el));
console.log(as)
```

If you're receiving a string you have to parse it:

```js
const test = `{
"test":[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Robert",
    "last_name": "Schwartz",
    "email": "rob23@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Lucy",
    "last_name": "Ballmer",
    "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Anna",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
  }
]
}`;
const as = JSON.parse(test).test.map(el => Object.values(el));
console.log(as)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing @zer00ne answer with ES 6

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "first": "Robert",
    "last": "Schwartz",
    "email": "rob23@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first": "Lucy",
    "last": "Ballmer",
    "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Anna",
    "last": "Smith",
    "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
  }
];

const convert = arrOfObj => {
  const keyArr = Object.keys(arrOfObj[0]);
  return arrOfObj.map(obj => keyArr.map(key => obj[key]));
};

console.log(convert(data));
```